# Issue setting integer value in Excel with NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, npoi

I have an Excel row where I need to write `5` using NPOI in the first column and `7.0` in the second column. Writing those values is quite simple, but when I need to write both in the same row, the `5` is formatted as `5.0`.

To write `5`, I use:

```
public static void SetCellValue(IRow row)
{
    var cell = row.CreateCell(1); // column 1
    int value = 5;
    cell.SetCellType(CellType.Numeric);
    cell.SetCellValue(value); 

    // 5 is written
}
```

To write `7.0`, I use:

```
public static void SetCellValue(IRow row)
{
    var cell = row.CreateCell(2); // column 2
    int value = 7;
    cell.SetCellType(CellType.Numeric);
    cell.SetCellValue(value); 

    var dataFormat = cell.Sheet.Workbook.CreateDataFormat();
    var strFormat = "0.0";
    cell.CellStyle.DataFormat = dataFormat.GetFormat(strFormat); 

    // 7.0 is written
}
```

To write `5` and `7.0`, I'm using:

```
public static void SetCellValue(IRow row)
{
    var cell1 = row.CreateCell(1); // column 1
    int value1 = 5;
    cell1.SetCellType(CellType.Numeric);
    cell1.SetCellValue(value1); 

    var cell2 = row.CreateCell(2); // column 2
    int value2 = 7;
    cell2.SetCellType(CellType.Numeric);
    cell2.SetCellValue(value2); 

    var dataFormat = cell2.Sheet.Workbook.CreateDataFormat();
    var strFormat = "0.0";
    cell2.CellStyle.DataFormat = dataFormat.GetFormat(strFormat); 

    // 5.0 and 7.0 is written and not 5 and 7.0
}
```

Any suggestions? I've tried to format the first element (number `5`) using formats like `var strFormat = "0";` and `var strFormat = "#";` but it remains as `5.0` and not as `5`

Additional note: I'm using [NPOI version 2.1.1](https://npoi.codeplex.com/releases/view/115353)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like NPOI, but sometimes I get myself in trouble with some weird bugs. Your issue seems one of that kind.

To solve this one, you have to:

1. Create a row in your Excel template and format it as you need.
2. Create a new row (where you want to write) copying from the formatted content.

```csharp
int formattedRowIndex = 1;
int newRowIndex = 2;
IRow row = sheet.CopyRow(formattedRowIndex, newRowIndex);
```

3. Write the values without applying any other formatting.

```csharp
row.CreateCell(1).setCellValue(5);
row.CreateCell(2).setCellValue(7);

// Output: 5 and 7.0
```

4. Remove the dummy row:

```csharp
sheet.RemoveRow(formattedRowIndex);
```